# Table Variable Style Entities in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been looking around for awhile for something in Oracle that acts like a table variable in SQL Server.  I've found people asking questions like this here on SO and people always say "Yes, Oracle has that" but the examples show that the entities are not like SQL Server at all.  Can someone show me how to perform the below simple TSQL solution in Oracle?

```
declare @users table (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Age int,
    Gender char(1)
)

;with users as (
    select 1001 as ID, 'Bob' as Name, 25 as Age, 'M' as Gender
    union
    select 1021 as ID, 'Sam' as Name, 29 as Age, 'F'
)
insert into @users (ID, Name, Age, Gender)
select *  from users

declare @grades table (
    UserID int,
    ClassID int,
    Grade int
)

;with grades as (
    select 1001 as UserID , 120 as ClassID, 4 as Grade
    Union
    select 1001 as UserID , 220 as ClassID, 2 as Grade
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 130 as ClassID, 4 as Grade
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 230 as ClassID, 4 as Grade
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 340 as ClassID, 2 as Grade
)
insert into @grades
select * from grades

select u.ID, u.Name, GPA = AVG(cast(g.grade as decimal))
from @users u
    inner join @grades g on u.ID=g.UserID
group by u.ID, u.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers may tell you that Oracle has table variables, and it does to a certain extent. However, most answers will tell you that you should not be doing this in Oracle at all; there's simply no need.

In your case I would simply use a CTE:

```
with users as (
    select 1001 as ID, 'Bob' as Name, 25 as Age, 'M' as Gender from dual
    union
    select 1021 as ID, 'Sam' as Name, 29 as Age, 'F' from dual
          )
 , grades as (
    select 1001 as UserID , 120 as ClassID, 4 as Grade from dual
    Union
    select 1001 as UserID , 220 as ClassID, 2 as Grade from dual
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 130 as ClassID, 4 as Grade from dual
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 230 as ClassID, 4 as Grade from dual
    Union
    select 1021 as UserID , 340 as ClassID, 2 as Grade from dual
           )
select u.ID, u.Name, AVG(g.grade) as gpa
  from users u
  join grades g on u.ID = g.UserID
 group by u.ID, u.Name
```

UPDATE: The answer I've been trying to get for a long time is in Ben's comment below which I include here: 
"There is no variable, which you can create on the fly and join to other tables in standard SQL @wcm, yes. There is a number of different type of objects that can be created that will allow you to do this, but not exactly as you would in T-SQL".

Comment: So you are saying that even though there are arrays and collections of various types, we don't have table variables that act like tables that can be joined to other tables using standard SQL?

Comment: There is no variable, which you can create on the fly and join to other tables in standard SQL @wcm, yes. There is a number of different type of objects that can be created that will allow you to do this, but not exactly as you would in T-SQL.

Comment: By other types of objects, are you referring to global temporary tables?

Comment: Not necessarily @wcm, but that's one way; yes. You can also use a user-defined type, a nested table etc.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you please show an example of using a user defined type that would allow me to use it in a sql statement?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, then if I needed temporary storage of data that is confined to being visible to my session, then I'd be using a global temporary table. Probably more overhead than storing in memory, but plenty of advantages too -- gathering statistics on them, indexing them, and the ability to store data without regard to memory consumption.

Comment: The way I've seen global temporary tables used has always been for long term solutions and not the ad hoc type of uses that I'm looking for.  Also, don't you need elevated rights in the DB in order to create these objects?